# Git checkout fails when trying to checkout while in VirtualBox shared folder

Tags: git, virtualbox

I have cloned a repository into my Windows 7 desktop. I've setup the repository as a shared folder in my VirtualBox machine (`Ubuntu 14.04`). So now I can access this folder in my Ubuntu VBox machine.

When I try to perform `git checkout branch-v1` it says:

```
error: The following untracked working tree files would be overwritten by checkout:
path/to/file/foo.java
Please move or remove them before you can switch branches.
Aborting
```

But, when I go back to my Win7 host, open cygwin and do `git checkout branch-v1`, it works fine.

So, how can I checkout on guest without having this issue all the time?

Note: I'm not working on the `foo.java` file. It's not open in a text editor or something like that.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like a problem with line endings. Try `git config --global core.autocrlf true`

Guide on github: [Dealing with line endings](https://help.github.com/articles/dealing-with-line-endings/)

Comment: Didn't help, I still get the same issue.